# HP 4515s, XP SP 3, how can I fix not working audio?

Tags: laptop, drivers, audio

I've installed all drivers from HP site but SoundMAX drivers throws exception like "ADI SoundMAX XP Audio Driver no device" and one driver just unpack itself to my drivers folder and don't run setup and if try to run setup manually nothing happens.

Same problem with installing Realtek drivers.

Here is screenshot of my devices:

[[image] (Click to enlarge)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aGKAp.png)

Answer (score 0):

Did you install the "The High-Definition (HD) Bus Driver from Microsoft Knowledge Base Article 888111" that is listed as "must be installed BEFORE installing this SoftPaq"? for both the ADI SoundMAX AD1984A Audio Driver for Microsoft Windows XP and the IDT High-Definition (HD) Audio Driver?

Comment: Yes I've installed it. But Service Pack 3 already include it.